# regular expression for line seperated different lengthy words

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I've got the below query from another post but seems its not working for single character.

```
SELECT regexp_substr('abc
def
ghi', '.+[[:alpha:]]', 1 ,level)
FROM dual
     CONNECT BY regexp_substr('abc
def
ghi', '.+[[:alpha:]]', 1 ,level) IS NOT NULL;
```

output

```
abc
def
ghi
```

When I try this for a single character it doesn't work as expected.

```
 SELECT regexp_substr('a
b
c', '.+[[:alpha:]]', 1 ,level)
FROM dual
     CONNECT BY regexp_substr('a
b
c', '.+[[:alpha:]]', 1 ,level) IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of your regular expression. Change it to look for *just* consecutive alphabetic characters:

```
 select regexp_substr('abc
 def
 ghi', '[[:alpha:]]+', 1 ,level)
   from dual
connect by regexp_substr('abc
def
ghi', '[[:alpha:]]+', 1 ,level) is not null
```

It works for single characters as well:

```
select regexp_substr('a
b
c', '[[:alpha:]]+', 1 ,level)
from dual
     connect by regexp_substr('a
b
c', '[[:alpha:]]+', 1 ,level) is not null;
```

You've commented:

> but my actual requirement is that , the single line may or maynot have single word, or a single character, which also contains numbers , spaces etc ., for example: 'this is a number333

Please always put all the information in the question to begin with please.

You seem to be looking to split on a newline character (carriage return or carriage return/line feed)

In which case you're looking to split where something is *not* one of these characters. I've used all control characters here because I'm lazy but it will work for your provided data. If you have some Bell characters this won't work, you'll have to be more specific.

```
with the_data as ( 
select 'a
b
c' as dat
  from dual
       )
 select regexp_substr(dat, '[^[:cntrl:]]+', 1 ,level)
  from the_data
connect by regexp_substr(dat, '[^[:cntrl:]]+', 1 ,level) is not null;
```

Comment: but my actual requirement is that , the single line may or may not have single word, or a single character, which also contains numbers , spaces etc ., for example: 'this is a number: 333'

Comment: perfect!.. I should've to be specific. But I am getting different data at times. But as of now it all seems well. Thanks again. I actually didn't get the tactic behind using these types of regexp.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT regexp_substr('a
b
c', '[[:alpha:]]', 1 ,level)
FROM dual
CONNECT BY regexp_substr('a
b
c', '[[:alpha:]]', 1 ,level) IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: I thought OP want to match only one character