# oracle regular expression and MERGE

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql, merge

As updating my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17360371/regular-expression-for-line-seperated-different-lengthy-words%22%3Equestion),

I've a some newline separated strings.
I need to insert those each words into a table.
The new logic and its condition is that,  it should be inserted if not exists, or update the corresponding count by 1. (as like using MERGE).
But my current query is just using insert, so I've used CONNECT BY LEVEL method without checking the value is existing or not.

it syntax is somewhat like:

```
if the word already EXISTS THEN
UPDATE my_table set w_count = w_count +1 where word = '...';
else
INSERT INTO my_table (word, w_count)
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(i_words, '[^[:cntrl:]]+', 1 ,level),
     1
FROM dual
     CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(i_words, '[^[:cntrl:]]+', 1 ,level) IS NOT NULL;
end if;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
MERGE INTO my_table m
    USING(WITH the_data AS (
          SELECT 'a
                  bb

                  &
                  c' AS dat
          FROM dual
        )
         SELECT regexp_substr(dat, '[^[:cntrl:]]+', 1 ,LEVEL) wrd
         FROM the_data
         CONNECT BY regexp_substr(dat, '[^[:cntrl:]]+', 1 ,LEVEL) IS NOT NULL) word_list
    ON (word_list.wrd = m.word)
    WHEN matched THEN UPDATE SET m.w_count = m.w_count + 1
    WHEN NOT matched THEN insert(m.word,m.w_count) VALUES (word_list.wrd,1);
```

More details on `MERGE` [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606).

Sample [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ba2d7/1)

Comment: Prodigious!! Wonderful.. Thanks @horrendous-space-kablooie. The only problem is I cannot able to use sequence correctly (without gap) as per Oracle documentation.